# Eclipse Mars Configuration

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am facing couple of problems with projects configuration in Eclipse Mars/Kepler.

1. Build Path is not coming for projects.
2. Ctrl + click is not working
3. Ctrl + Shift + T not working.
4. Package view is not coming got projects.

I did lot googling and tried, but none are working.

Comment: What should those "not working" keys do, and what are they doing instead, and in what context? Are you sure the Java SDK plugin is installed at all? Also, what does this have to do with Maven?

Comment: Some problem could be with Eclipse itself while loading the libraries. I hope you have tried a restart of eclipse and creating a new workspace.

Comment: Where did you get your Eclipse from, and what "flavor" (Classic, Java, J2EE, ...)? Do you have those problems only with Mars and Kepler (Kepler, seriously?) but not with Luna and Neon?

Comment: @tobias_k Eclipse Mars download link: - http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/mars/2/eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64.zip    Java Version: - 1.8_45.  I am not sure with Luna and neon but I tried using Kepler and Mars, its not working.  Moreover to me it doesn't look like eclipse version problem

Comment: @Shinchan I tried restart of eclipse and workspace. not working

Comment: Ok. Go to problems view and check if you see any error logs.

Comment: @Shinchan I am reimporting all the projects. I will add the error once it get imported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue.
Eclipse Mars has an embedded maven plugin installed and configured in eclipse.
This was different from the version of eclipse configures on my system which I was using to "mvn clean install" the workspace. So, pointing to my system configured maven and re-importing the projects resolved the issue.
Go to Windows --> Preferences --> Maven --> Installations and point to system maven.
My projects are compatible with maven 3.2.3 (system maven) and eclipse has higher version of maven.